# Script to enable "source" downloads in a deterministic manner

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, scripts, software-sources

I wrote a couple of scripts to help users pull their current kernel source package, apply some patches of mine, and build it as a `.deb` package with `make-kpkg`. One of the few steps that requires manual intervention is enabling the "Source" downloads via:

- "Ubuntu Software Center"

  - Edit...

    - Software Sources...

      - "Source Code"

[image]

Is there a way to do this automatically via the command line? It's to my understanding I could just un-comment the first few "deb-src" lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, like so:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
```

This is somewhat error-prone though, given the `sed` scripts I've written don't necessarily work if the sources are out of the default order, or various other reasons. **More importantly, I'd like this to work on Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04, etc (ie: as generic as possible).**

Are there any command-line `apt`-related tools to accomplish this via a shell script?

Thank you.

Comment: There have been plenty of scripts done on this post : http://askubuntu.com/q/700860/295286  Let me know of any of those work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I just enabled all the `src` repos.

```
sed -i '/^#\sdeb-src /s/^#//' "/etc/apt/sources.list"
```

This doesn't require upgrading the OS to an arbitrary version.

Comment: This variant will do the job while keeping the `deb-src` lines nicely aligned on the left: `sed -i '/^#\sdeb-src /s/^# *//' "/etc/apt/sources.list"` .

Comment: Is there a reason why `''` and `""` are used. I know that it can make a difference in shell scripts. Is it possible to use one of them only? That would make it easier to use the snipplet when passing it as command argument, e.g. to `docker run`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem as you had and finaly I started doing the following script, to write a temporary `sources.list` and later removing it again:

```
# making a copy of the users original sources.list file
cp -v /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.orig &&

# writing a custom sources.list file
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list << "EOF"
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://dearchive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
EOF

# running an update
apt-get update &&
apt-get -y dist-upgrade &&

# DO YOUR STUFF

# putting back the original sources.list
mv -v /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.tmp &&
cp -v /etc/apt/sources.list.orig /etc/apt/sources.list &&

# removing backup files
rm -rfv /etc/apt/sources.list.tmp &&
rm -rfv /etc/apt/sources.list.orig
```

Comment: What if I'm not on Xenial, but on Trusty/(Wily, Vivid, etc), or Precise?

Comment: Well take your source file remove the lines with a `#` in front and replace the ones in my answer with them.

Comment: I could run a sed/bash regex easily enough to remove all leading `#` characters, but should I necessarily do that? Some of those sources in the list file enable sources that are either unsupported or bring licensing concerns into the fray. An enable-all approach seems a big hammer to throw at the problem.

Comment: Youre aware of the last step i have in my script approach? i remove my temporary sources.list and copy back the one the user had.

Comment: Yes. You're upgrading to the latest release, when all I want is to enable the repo for source for the latest release currently installed on the system.

Comment: @DevNull have you seen the question i posted ? the solutions there cover exactly the type of thing you want. Really, you can just use simple `sed` command to comment and uncomment `deb-src` lines , if you'd like that as a solution

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a perl one-liner that will uncomment only the `deb-src` lines that are preceded by an uncommented `deb` line:

```
perl -pi.orig -0e 's/^(deb .*\n)# (deb-src)/$1$2/mg' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It will also keep the original one as `/etc/apt/sources.list.orig`. (so you can restore it later if you want)

This *should* work across releases, assuming they continue their habit of putting commented-out `deb-src` lines right after their corresponding `deb` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting various pieces together, I came up with an easily reversible solution for enabling and disabling source downloads.

#### Enable source

From [cloud and Stéphane Gourichon's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/769429/913198), with [sed modified to ignore non-matching lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665662/10155767) and the output [redirected with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82553/10155767) to a temporary file under `sources.list.d/`:

```
sed -e '/^#\sdeb-src /s/^# *//;t;d' "/etc/apt/sources.list" \
| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/source-repos-tmp.list > /dev/null
```

#### Disable source

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/source-repos-tmp.list
```