# installing pspp v1.4.0 reguires gtksource 3.4.0+. I installed it but it does not find it!

Tags: gtk

- I was trying to install PSPP v1.4.0 from source.
- However, it reguires " GtkSourceView version 3.4.0 or later."
- I installed GtkSourceView v4.0.
- It cant find it - reports "You must install them before PSPP can be built:
  gtksourceview 3.0 version 3.4.2 or later (or use --without-gui)"
- `dpkg -s libgtk-3-0|grep '^Version'` says `Version: 3.22.30-1ubuntu4`

What I must do now in order pspp find the gtk 4? I can explicitly declaring at sudo
./configure command somehow?

UPDATE - dont knw if it helps...

I am trying to install gtk+3.4 (what is the difference with gtksource?)

then issuing `find /usr/ -iname "*glib*.pc"`

it reports that: No glib 3.....

```
  /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/fso-glib-1.0.pc
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libpulse-mainloop-glib.pc
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
    /usr/lib/pkgconfig/glib-sharp-3.0.pc
    /usr/lib/pkgconfig/glib-sharp-2.0.pc
```

Note that:

```
elias@eliasc:$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib64/
elias@eliasc:$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Note that for gtk+-3.4.2:

```
elias@eliasc:$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc 

*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.64.0, but GLIB (2.56.4)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
no
configure: error: 
*** GLIB 2.32.0 or better is required. The latest version of
*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/gtk/.
```

Note that it was installed gtksourceview-4.0.0 (for PSPP v1.4) from source successfully and glib-2.64.4 (for gtk+-3.4.2)  from source successfully but they do not appear to be "discovered" either by the respecting apps that need them.

Note that...

by choosing from Software & Updates, sources in first tab...
and by running "sudo apt-get build-dep pspp
" the libgtksourceview-3.0-dev is installed....

then... running sudo ./configure for pspp v1.4. is working. It was installed successfully!

Comment: Issues like this are almost always because you installed only the runtime library package - to build stuff from source, you need the development package(s) ex. `libgtk-3-dev`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev` `libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version (3.22.30-1ubuntu4).`

Comment: No, `libgtksourceview-3.0-dev` and `libgtk-3-dev` are not the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start the compilation process by getting build-dependencies for 18.04 LTS version:

1. Enable *Source Code* repositories by visiting Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`)

   [image: Software & Updates → Ubuntu Software]

   then confirm lists *Reload*.
2. Get build-dependencies with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep pspp
   ```
3. Resume the compilation as you have planned:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/Downloads/pspp
   cd ~/Downloads/pspp
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/spread-sheet-widget/spread-sheet-widget_0.6.orig.tar.gz
   tar -xf spread-sheet-widget_0.6.orig.tar.gz
   cd spread-sheet-widget-0.6/
   ./configure
   sudo make install

   cd ~/Downloads/pspp
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pspp/pspp_1.4.0.orig.tar.gz
   tar -xf pspp_1.4.0.orig.tar.gz
   cd pspp-1.4.0/
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: 1) in Other software in the "Software & Updates", there is no url for pspp or gtk. 2) "sudo apt-get build-dep pspp" says unable to locate package name". 3) Bionic has 1.0.1 version of pspp, while now is at 1.4.0. What i must do?

Comment: Enable source code repositories on the first tab of Software & Updates, then follow the guide. I have tested it, it resulted in fully operational PSPP.

Comment: What version of PSPP; I want 1.4.0 version... the latest one cause a very important bug was fixed. Yes, it is enable.

Comment: You have chosen compilation method, the method above takes you with this process to get PSPP 1.4.0. Read the commands before execution and you will see and learn what is happening here.

Comment: I have downloaded source code to compile from scratch. No pspp repisitory exists in the soiftware and Updates...

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Now you can follow the guide accurately.

Comment: Finally, i did it. I havent notice "-" in choosing source. https://askubuntu.com/questions/768943/script-to-enable-source-downloads-in-a-deterministic-manner - It does nt install v1.4.0. I have pspp 1.2.0

Comment: When i run now "sudo apt-get build-dep pspp" it says 0 updated, 0 new installed 0 removed...

Comment: Now, sudo ./configure is working... for pspp.... please add ... in your solution "by choosing from Software & Updates, "sources" in first tab... and by running "sudo apt-get build-dep pspp " the libgtksourceview-3.0-dev is installed...." that is needed from PSPPire