# How to enable or disable -updates, -security, -backports, -proposed repositories from commandline?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

Let's assume that we are using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

I know GUI ways to enable or disable the following repositories:

1. **Important security updates**  (`bionic-security`)
2. **Recommended updates** (`bionic-updates`)
3. **Pre-released updates** (`bionic-proposed`)
4. **Unsupported updates** (`bionic-backports`)

In KDE user may want to open *Software & Updates* (or `software-properties-kde`) and navigate to *Updates* tab.
In GNOME, MATE, Xfce user should open *Software & Updates* (or `software-properties-gtk`) and navigate to *Updates* tab for `-security`, `-updates` and `-backports` and *Developer options* tab for `-proposed`.

But how to enable or disable `-updates`, `-security`, `-backports`, `-proposed` repositories from commandline?

**Note: I need a solution without direct editing of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.**

Update: I created [discussion and poll named "Does Ubuntu need console alternative for software-properties-gtk / software-properties-kde?" on community.ubuntu.com](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/does-ubuntu-need-console-alternative-for-software-properties-gtk-software-properties-kde/8763?u=norbert).

Comment: In Kubuntu 18.04, `software-properties-kde` has `NoDisplay=true` and so won't be seen normally. Now one has to open `Discover` then click on `Settings` and then on ☰ in order to access the GUI of `software-properties-kde`. The other option (which I've taken) is to copy `software-properties-kde.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications` and comment out `NoDisplay=true`.

Comment: Is this a one-time disable, or do you want to be able to switch them on/off regularly? One ongoing solution is to disable /etc/apt/sources.list entirely by replacing it with a dummy file, then programmatically creating/deleting individual files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. Rather like applications can insert/remove files in cron.daily. Another solution is to create a series of source files in different permutations, and select the correct file using `apt-config`. I don't think apt-config permits you to drop sources after they have been loaded.

Comment: @user535733 I wanted to have simple toggle like `add-apt-repository` / `add-apt-repository -r` does for PPAs. The `apt-config` idea sounds interesting.

Comment: So, are you wanting a script or tool that modifies `sources.list` or do you just not want to touch that file at all? I'm pretty sure enabling/disabling those items in the software GUI just removes / adds those items, not sure how you would do it any other way. A script to add/remove each of those items is fairly trivial.

Comment: This question is pretty much a duplicate of [Add and remove update channels in an easy terminal way](https://askubuntu.com/q/700860/295286). Sadly since it's got bounty, we can't close it yet but feel free to choose from like 4 answers there. There's answers in Perl, Python, and Awk ( written by me ). And let's just say, there's no "easy" command-line way. Adding those repositories - security, backports, etc - is all done by parsing/editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: I need a solution without direct editing of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Would using `find` and `sed` to comment out the lines be considered *direct editing*?

To disable these lines:

```
find /etc/apt -type f -name '*.list' -exec sed -i 's/\(^deb.*-backports.*\)/#\1/; s/\(^deb.*-updates.*\)/#\1/; s/\(^deb.*-proposed.*\)/#\1/; s/\(^deb.*-security.*\)/#\1/' {} +
```

Alternatively, we can just delete them:

```
find /etc/apt -type f -name '*.list' -exec sed -i '/-backports/d; /-updates/d; /-proposed/d; /-security/d' {} +
```

To enable them again:

```
find /etc/apt -type f -name '*.list' -exec sed -i 's/^#\(deb.*-backports.*\)/\1/; s/^#\(deb.*-updates.*\)/\1/; s/^#\(deb.*-proposed.*\)/\1/; s/^#\(deb.*-security.*\)/\1/' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And uncomment the lines/sources you need.

Comment: The OP explicitely wrote "I need a solution without direct editing of /etc/apt/sources.list".