# Enable automatic updates from command line

Tags: bash, scripts, update-manager

I'm creating a BASH script that will, among other things, enable automatic updates, important security updates, and the "Check daily" option in the software updates menu. But no matter where i search, i cant find an answer. From what i can tell, the only way to do it is through the GUI. Is there anyway to do this that im missing?

EDIT 1:
     Through some more research, I have figured out how to enable important securty updates and reccomended updates with this bit of code:

```
find /etc/apt -type f -name '*.list' -exec sed -i 's/^#\(deb.*-backports.*\)/\1/; s/^#\(deb.*-updates.*\)/\1/; s/^#\(deb.*-proposed.*\)/\1/; s/^#\(deb.*-security.*\)/\1/' {} +
```

From [How to enable or disable -updates, -security, -backports, -proposed repositories from commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093450/how-to-enable-or-disable-updates-security-backports-proposed-repositories)

Comment: So to clarify, you're still looking for how to enable automatic updates and enable the "Check daily" option, right? What version of Ubuntu are you asking about?

Comment: Instead of sed-ing files, you can simply place your own config file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d. Give it a high number like "99-my-config-changes" so it takes precedence over earlier-loaded config settings. Custom configs are rarely neccessary - unattended-upgrades has sane default settings.

Comment: I am currently using ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and yes i am still looking for the Check daily option

Comment: Editing sources.list files isn't directly related to updating automatically... the sources choose where to update from, but not when. And which program do you want to use/edit, unattended-upgrades, gnome update manager, cron & aptitude, cron-apt?

Comment: @Xen2050 I want to edit whatever file the GUI uses when you change it manually, i want the exact same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the `unattended-upgrades` package and it's already  installed, then according to [Ubuntu's Community Help Wiki on AutomaticSecurityUpdates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) (FYI it also has info on using GNOME Update Manager, cron and aptitude, and cron-apt):

> ### Determining the current configuration
>
> The current configuration can be queried by running:
>
> ```
> apt-config dump APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade
> ```
>
> Which will produce output like:
>
> ```
> APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
> ```
>
> In this example, Unattended Upgrade will run every 1 day. If the number is "0" then unattended upgrades are disabled.
>
> The files in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ are evaluated in lexicographical order with each file capable of overriding values set in earlier files. *This makes it insufficient to view the setting in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades and why it is recommended to use apt-config.*
>
> ---
>
> To enable it, do:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades
> ```
>
> (it's an interactive dialog) which will create `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. And `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` with the following contents:
>
> ```
> APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
> APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
> ```
>
> Details about what these values mean may be found in the header of the /etc/cron.daily/apt file.

If you're absolutely sure you wouldn't miss out on anything else `dpkg-reconfigure` does (I'm not sure the above is an exhaustive list), you could just create/edit the above files.

Or instead of the above, according to the [Debian wiki on UnattendedUpgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades):

> ## Automatic call via /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic
>
> Alternatively, you can also create the apt configuration file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic` to activate unattended-upgrades:
>
> Below is an example /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic:
>
> ```
> // Control parameters for cron jobs by /etc/cron.daily/apt-compat //
>
> // Enable the update/upgrade script (0=disable)
> APT::Periodic::Enable "1";
>
> // Do "apt-get update" automatically every n-days (0=disable)
> APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
>
> // Do "apt-get upgrade --download-only" every n-days (0=disable)
> APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
>
> // Run the "unattended-upgrade" security upgrade script
> // every n-days (0=disabled)
> // Requires the package "unattended-upgrades" and will write
> // a log in /var/log/unattended-upgrades
> APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
>
> // Do "apt-get autoclean" every n-days (0=disable)
> APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "21";
>
>
> // Send report mail to root
> //  0: no report         (or null string)
> //  1: progress report   (actually any string)
> //  2: + command outputs (remove -qq, remove 2>/dev/null, add -d)
> //  3: + trace on
> APT::Periodic::Verbose "2";
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ## Manual run (for debugging)
>
> To aid debugging you may need to run unattended-upgrades manually thus:
>
> ```
> sudo unattended-upgrade -d
> ```
>
> ## See Also
>
> - /usr/share/doc/unattended-upgrades/README.md.gz
> - /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz
> - /etc/cron.daily/apt
> - [apt.conf(5)](http://manpages.debian.org/apt.conf)

Also, some more info you might be interested in:

> ## Related systemd files
>
> Because Debian is using the  systemd  system, it has timers defined for APT use, these files are provided by the apt package.
>   The relevant files are:
>
> - Used for **downloads**: `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer`
>
>   - override with `/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.d/override.conf`
> - Used for upgrading: `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer`
>
>   - override with `/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.d/override.conf`
>
> You can override these settings using local override files as shown above, creating the missing parts if non-existent yet.
>
> Here is an example of how to override the download time to 1AM using  `/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.d/override.conf` :
>
> ```
> [Timer]
> OnCalendar=
> OnCalendar=01:00
> ```
>
> Line #2 above is needed to reset (empty) the default value shown below in line #5.
>
> The default in `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer` is (at moment of this writing):
>
> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=Daily apt download activities
>
> [Timer]
> OnCalendar=*-*-* 6,18:00
> RandomizedDelaySec=12h
> Persistent=true
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=timers.target
> ```

Comment: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/21005) tells more about overriding systemd timers (and other stuff)

Answer (score 8):

**Unattended upgrades are enabled by default** in all Ubuntu releases 16.04 and newer.

There are three easy ways to tell if the `unattended-upgrades` package is installed and working.

1. **See if the package is installed**. Look for "[installed]" at the end of the bottom line of output.

   ```
    $ apt list unattended-upgrades
    Listing... Done
    unattended-upgrades/cosmic-updates,cosmic-updates,now 1.5ubuntu3.18.10.1 all [installed]
   ```
2. **Check the apt timestamps** for unattended-upgrades activity. Look for a timestamp by unattended-upgrades within the past day or two:

   ```
    $ ls -la /var/lib/apt/periodic/
    total 8
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 15  2017 .
    drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan  1 08:24 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan 10 07:54 download-upgradeable-stamp
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan 10 07:51 unattended-upgrades-stamp
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan 10 07:52 update-stamp
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan 10 07:53 update-success-stamp
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan 10 07:55 upgrade-stamp
   ```
3. **Check the apt settings** to see if Unattended Upgrades is turned on ("1") or off ("0"):

   ```
    $ grep Unattended-Upgrade /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades 
    APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
   ```

**The repositories that unattended-upgrades uses** are listed in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrade.

- The -security repository is enabled by default in all releases of Ubuntu.
- Adding other Ubuntu repositories is trivial: Simply uncomment the appropriate line.
- Enabling -backports is discouraged, those packages are not fully tested.
- Enabling -proposed is STRONGLY DISCOURAGED, as those packages can be very risky.

If unattended-upgrades is installed and turned on, **it will run daily whether you want it to or not**. Only the GUI provides the option to change the period.

**After you make changes** you do not need to restart your system. Apt runs once daily at a random time, and reloads the configs and sources anew each time.

Comment: most of this doesnt really help me, i checked to confirm that "Unattenended-upgrades" is installed and working, but i want this script to set automatic updates to daily, regardless of what machine i run it on. The machines that this script will be run on will most likely have it set to "Never"

Comment: It's long because you were heading down a more difficult road than you need to.

Comment: so, i didnt really get a clear answer though. How exactly do i enable automatic checking for updates daily?

Comment: u-u ignores the GUI setting, and runs daily when enabled. The GUI control is older; from before the days when u-u was enabled by default. If you want standardization, there are several easy ways.

Comment: This is a great answer for the question https://askubuntu.com/questions/172524/how-can-i-check-if-automatic-updates-are-enabled

Answer (score 0):

`echo -e 'APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "7";\nAPT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "7";\nAPT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "7";\nAPT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

only security auto updates..  `sed -i 's/"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";/\/\/"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";/' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

notifs: `apt install apticron && echo -e 'EMAIL=$EMAIL' >> /etc/apticron/apticron.conf`

`echo -e "[Timer]\nPersistent=delay" > /etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer.d/override.conf`   this is to prevent uu on boot, though default set to random  (systemctl list-timers)

`unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug && cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`