# How to install perf on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, updates, repository, official-repositories

I have tried to install `perf` using `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-$(uname -r) linux-tools-generic`

It gives an error saying:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... 
Done E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-4.18.0-21-generic 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-4.18.0-21-generic' 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-4.18.0-21-generic' –
```

**(EDIT)**

I did run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` before running the above command, but I still get the same error message as above.

I ran `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and got the following message:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
```

`uname -a` yields: `Linux ubuntu 4.18.0-21-generic #22~18.04.1-Ubuntu  SMP Thu May 16 15:07:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

[output of `apt list 'linux-tools-*'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0evl.png)

[output of `apt list --installed 'linux-*'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THhtw.png)

Comment: Apologies. I have made those edits

Comment: Thanks. The output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` shows you don't have either of the repositories that provide updated software enabled. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` was quite short, containing only two non-blank lines. It revealed that `/etc/apt/sources.list` has the `bionic` repository but is missing the `bionic-updates` and `bionic-security` repositories, which are typically present and enabled.

Adding them should fix the problem. The package you're trying to install, `linux-tools-4.18.0-21-generic`, is provided in `bionic-updates`.

Since all official updates to stable releases are released through the `-security` and `-updates` repositories, you may find a number of updates available for installation. It's a good idea to install those, unless you have a specific and important reason not to do so.

You can enable those repositories [with the `add-apt-repository` command](https://askubuntu.com/a/701658/22949) or with either of the methods summarized below. Or you may want to follow one of the procedures given at [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

### Graphically

If your system has a graphical desktop installed, you can run the Software & Updates tool and enable them from there. To do that:

1. Open *Software & Updates*.
2. Click the *Updates* tab.
3. Under "Install updates from:" make sure these boxes are checked:

   - Important security updates (bionic-security)
   - Recommended updates (bionic-updates)

   For this purpose, it doesn't matter much whether or not the "Unsupported updates" box is checked. Most users will generally prefer *not* to enable that repository.

   You may need to enter a password to change those settings. That's normal.
4. Click *Close*.
5. You will be told, "The information about available software is out-of-date." Click *Reload*.
6. You should now be able to install the `linux-tools-4.18.0-21-generic` package. Go ahead and attempt to do so.

### Manually, by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`

If you have no GUI or prefer to manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you can do so. Normally I would recommend backing up the file you have, but what you have doesn't contain very much. Still, if you want to you can do so by running `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list{,.bak}`. You can then edit the file. It's owned by root; I suggest editing it with `sudoedit`. You can run:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you have a specific editor you prefer `sudoedit` to use, you can specify that. For example, to use `nano` even if that's not the default, you could run this instead:

```
VISUAL=nano sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After editing, the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file should look like:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main universe restricted multiverse
```

The lines that start with `deb-src` provide source code packages. Including them may make `sudo apt update` take slightly longer each time it is run, but does not incur any other significant overhead. Still, if you don't want to able to download source code automatically through the package manager, you can comment them out (by placing a `#` at the beginning of each line you wish to deactivate) or even omit them. You can (re)enable them later.

You may want to use a mirror instead of the master site, to get faster downloads. For example, the main US mirror would be used if you wrote `us.archive.ubuntu.com` instead of `archive.ubuntu.com`. Your current `deb` and `deb-src` lines don't use one, so I didn't either in what I wrote above. I mainly mention this to point out that *if you do* decide to use one, you should still keep the URLs in the `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` lines unchanged.

Comment: Great Answer! Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct command to install linux-tools for actually used kernel (from official repository) is:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-`uname -r`
```

Comment: I get the same error message even when I run this command

Comment: Please put here the output with this error. "`" is from the tilda key.

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done   
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-4.18.0-21-generic    
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-4.18.0-21-generic'    
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-4.18.0-21-generic'`

Comment: I wasn't able to add a line-break for some reason, sorry for the formatting of the comment

Comment: Do you have enabled updates repository for your ubuntu release? Did you do `apt get update` before?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it still gives the same error message

Comment: Which one of mirror server you use? Maybe it is a problem with them. Please look here: http://ubuntu.task.gda.pl/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/ The package for which you are looking for is available.

Btw. Your and my command are correct. Both works well for me.